# Is there an query for selecting all the rows from one table and selecting one row from another table?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display a combination of two tables in which all rows will be there from first table and only 1 row from second table on some condition.

I was using left join suggest me some solutions

Comment: You should give your table Structure & Sample Data

Comment: The way you have given the Post , this will work : `"SELECT * FROM TABLE1 ; SELECT * FROM TABLE2 LIMIT 1 ;"` : I am sure you want something more specific but you should give specific table & Data.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. We like to help, but we are not magicians. Please help us help you by providing a detailed question, particularly: DDL (tables, other DB objects involved), Expected output, What have you tried so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `UNION` or `UNION ALL`.

It basically appends the results of two queries.

So your query would look somewhat like

```sql
select a, b, c from oneTable
UNION ALL
select x, y, z from otherTable where id = 23
```

The individual select can have where clauses and all kinds of stuff you know from SQL.